# oracle group by when value is zero, aggregate = 0

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, group-by

i am trying to build a query but it's taking me too much time to resolve it.

Oracle database v18

this is my table1

| Date1 | tagname | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 0:01 | a | 2 |
| 01/01/2021 0:02 | a | 4 |
| 01/01/2021 0:01 | b | 2 |
| 01/01/2021 0:02 | b | 4 |
| 01/01/2021 0:01 | c | 2 |
| 01/01/2021 0:02 | c | 4 |
| 02/01/2021 0:01 | a | 0 |
| 02/01/2021 0:02 | a | 0 |
| 02/01/2021 0:01 | b | 2 |
| 02/01/2021 0:02 | b | 4 |
| 02/01/2021 0:01 | c | 2 |
| 02/01/2021 0:02 | c | 4 |

i am doing an average by day

```
select avg(value) value, tagname, to_date(date1,'dd/MM/yyyy') 
from table1 
group by date1, tagname
```

Result:

| Date1 | tagname | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | a | 3 |
| 01/01/2021 | b | 3 |
| 01/01/2021 | c | 3 |
| 02/01/2021 | a | 0 |
| 02/01/2021 | b | 3 |
| 02/01/2021 | c | 3 |

now i need to add a new tagname

```
select sum(value), 'newtag' tagname 
from result
where tagname= 'a' or tagname = 'b' or tagname= 'c'
group by date1
```

but when a=0 newtag value = 0

How could i archieve this?

example

| Date1 | tagname | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | a | 3 |
| 01/01/2021 | b | 3 |
| 01/01/2021 | c | 3 |
| 01/01/2021 | newtag | 9 |
| 02/01/2021 | a | 0 |
| 02/01/2021 | b | 3 |
| 02/01/2021 | c | 3 |
| **02/01/2021** | **newtag** | **0** |

could i use case in this query?

thanks in advance

**Edit**: table1 have more tagnames, but only need to sum(a+b+c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first average by day

```
with avgday as (select avg(value) value, tagname, to_date(date1,'dd/MM/yyyy') 
from table1 group by date1, tagname)
```

transform row's to columns and doing a case to filter and operate.

```
with query1 as (SELECT *  FROM avgday  PIVOT (  MAX(value) FOR tagname IN ('a','b','c')))
select  date1, case 
when   query1.a=0 
 then 0 
else a + b + c end value, 
'newtag' tagname
 from query1
```

I finally came up with a solution, sure it's not the best answer, but it solves my problem

Answer (score 2):

So, this is easy to do with `UNION ALL`, of course.  I guess your concern is that you do not want to read through your table twice (once to calculate date/tag aggregates and again to calculate date aggregates).

Anytime you want to aggregate query results at multiple levels, you should at least consider `GROUPING SETS` functionality.

The trick in your case isn't the multiple-level aggregates.  Rather, it is that you want the 2nd level aggregate (by date) to be the `SUM()` of aggregates calculated at the first level (by date/tag).

To do that, you can use a window function to compute the `AVG()` by date/tag before any aggregates are done at all.  That makes it possible to `SUM()` them later.  Here is a working example (Oracle 12.1):

```
-- Create table with test data
create table my_table1 (Date1,  tagname,    Value) AS (
SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2021 0:01','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'a',    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2021 0:02','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'a',    4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2021 0:01','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'b',    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2021 0:02','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'b',    4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2021 0:01','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'c',    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2021 0:02','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'c',    4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('02/01/2021 0:01','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'a',    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('02/01/2021 0:02','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'a',    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('02/01/2021 0:01','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'b',    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('02/01/2021 0:02','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'b',    4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('02/01/2021 0:01','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'c',    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('02/01/2021 0:02','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'c',    4 FROM DUAL
)
;

-- Compute the averages and the use GROUPING SETS to use those those
-- averages conditionally at multiple levels of aggregation
with date_tag_summary as (
select trunc(date1) date1, tagname, avg(value) avg_value
from my_table1
group by trunc(date1), tagname )
select date1, 
       case when grouping(tagname)=1 then 'newtag' ELSE tagname END tagname, 
       case when grouping(tagname)=1 AND COUNT(DECODE(avg_value,0,1,NULL)) > 0 THEN 0
            when grouping(tagname)=1 THEN sum(avg_value)
            ELSE min(avg_value) END value
from date_tag_summary
group by grouping sets ( (date1, tagname), (date1) )
order by 1,2;
```

> ```
> +-----------+---------+-------+
> |   DATE1   | TAGNAME | VALUE |
> +-----------+---------+-------+
> | 01-JAN-21 | a       |     3 |
> | 01-JAN-21 | b       |     3 |
> | 01-JAN-21 | c       |     3 |
> | 01-JAN-21 | newtag  |     9 |
> | 02-JAN-21 | a       |     0 |
> | 02-JAN-21 | b       |     3 |
> | 02-JAN-21 | c       |     3 |
> | 02-JAN-21 | newtag  |     0 |
> +-----------+---------+-------+
> ```

And, to illustrate that the data is not being read twice, here is the execution plan for that query:

> ```
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Id  | Operation             | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |           |       |       |     6 (100)|          |
> |   1 |  SORT ORDER BY        |           |     3 |    63 |     6  (50)| 00:00:01 |
> |   2 |   SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP|           |     3 |    63 |     6  (50)| 00:00:01 |
> |   3 |    VIEW               |           |     9 |   189 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
> |   4 |     HASH GROUP BY     |           |     9 |   117 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
> |   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| MY_TABLE1 |    12 |   156 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Comment: thanks, i didn't say that in original post, but i have more tags, but only need to sum (a+b+c) there is a way to only operate with especified tags?,
and how i know that i filter with 'a', if i want to filter with 'b'?

Answer (score 1):

One method generates the rows using a `cross join` and then brings in the existing results:

```
select d.date1, t.tagname, avg(value) value
from (select distinct to_date(date1, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as date1 from table1
     ) d cross join
     (select 'a' as tagname from dual union all
      select 'b' as tagname from dual union all
      select 'c' as tagname from dual union all
      select 'd' as tagname from dual
     ) t
     table1 t1
     on to_date(t1.date1, 'dd/MM/yyyy') = d.date1 and
        t1.tagname = t.tagname
group by date1, tagname
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont see where is doing the sum in d tagname, anyway i dont want to repeat all tag's because this is a long list.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `grouping sets` and then replace avg total for group with sum of averages, calculated by analytic function.

> ```
> select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */
>   trunc(date1) as dt
>   , case grouping_id(tagname)
>       when 0
>       then tagname
>       else 'newtag'
>     end as tagname
>   , case grouping_id(tagname)
>       when 0
>       then avg(value)
>       else (
>         /*Total sum except total avg*/
>         sum(avg(value)) over(
>           partition by trunc(date1)
>         ) - avg(value))
>           * decode(min(avg(value)) over(partition by trunc(date1)), 0, 0, 1)
>     end as val
>       
> from a
> group by grouping sets( (trunc(date1), tagname), trunc(date1))
> ```
>
> ```
> DT        | TAGNAME | VAL
> :-------- | :------ | --:
> 01-JAN-21 | a       |   3
> 01-JAN-21 | b       |   3
> 01-JAN-21 | c       |   3
> 01-JAN-21 | newtag  |   9
> 02-JAN-21 | a       |   0
> 02-JAN-21 | b       |   3
> 02-JAN-21 | c       |   3
> 02-JAN-21 | newtag  |   0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=11da577f3e4a6bd4f4d07496579bb454)*

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak No magic: it just sums up all the averages and for total row subtracts average of that row (to exclude it from the result). What about 7 instead of 4: I cannot reproduce it in the attached fiddle. But yes, it is more or less the same within a single query instead of group by the same columns twice (not better/worse).

Comment: thanks, i just edited my original post, i have more tags, only need to sum(a+b+c)

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query. Of course it is set in SQL

```
;WITH cte AS
  (SELECT convert(date,date1) as date1,tagname,avg(value) value
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY convert(date,date1),tagname)

select date1,tagname,
   case when tagname = 'newtag' 
   then 
       case (select cte.value from cte where cte.date1 = result.date1 and cte.tagname = 'a') 
       when 0 then 0 
       else (select top 1 sum(c.value) from cte c where convert(date,c.date1,103) = result.date1)
       end
   else value end

from
(select date1,tagname,value ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by date1,tagname order by date1) as seq
from
  (
    select convert(date,date1) as date1,tagname,avg(value) as value
    from table1
    group by convert(date,date1),tagname


    union all


    select convert(date,date1),'newtag', 0
    from table1
    group by convert(date,date1),tagname
  ) T
) result
where result.seq = 1
order by convert(date,date1)
```